# How do I set the background of an Activity with code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm currently using the XML layout to set my Activity background. How can I do this in the Java code instead?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an id attribute to your parent RelativeLayout. Than find it by id in activity code and use setBackgroundResource method.

Comment: While this is equivalent to the code you're using above, both approaches lead to an extra level of overdraw that can affect your app's drawing performance. The best way to set an activity background is with a custom Theme setting a windowBackground drawable. More info is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html Make sure you're basing off of the Theme.Holo family if you're on Honeycomb or above to get the modern UI on devices that support it.

Answer (score 2):

Before calling [`Activity.setContentView(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29) use one of the [`setBackground...()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) methods on your main `View`.

Comment: I'm not seeing that function in my Activity class.

Comment: and why would set the background if after the setContent() it is comming a Relative view with `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`?

Comment: No, I mean I'm not seeing setBackground().

Comment: Edited again. The base class View has 3 variants of the method.